# sessionFactory configuration in spring with hibernate version 4+

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When we use Hibernate 3.x with Spring, we can configure our `localSessionFactoryBean` using `postProcess` methods:

1. `postProcessMappings`
2. `postProcessConfiguration`

But when I use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` with Hibernate version 4+ this methods seems have been deleted from `LocalSessionFactoryBean` class. Does Spring add some other ability for configuration `sessionFactory` like in previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are removed from the previous version in hibernate, many of them are deprecated. You code requires significant updating to use a new brand. `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is not an exception. Use `ServiceRegistryBuilder` to provide services required to use newly baked session factory bean.